# Simplify if statements used to determine response for different file types

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using a lot of if statements in my function to determine which content-type response to return for each different type of files based on their extension like below :

```
if(($post->ext == 'doc') || ($post->ext == 'docx')) {
            return (new Response($file, 200))->header('Content-Type', 'application/msword');
        }

if(($post->ext == 'xls') || ($post->ext == 'xlsx')) {
            return (new Response($file, 200))->header('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
        }

if(($post->ext == 'ppt') || ($post->ext == 'pptx')) {
            return (new Response($file, 200))->header('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint');
        }

if($post->ext == 'pdf') {
            return (new Response($file, 200))->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        }

if($post->ext == 'zip') {
            return (new Response($file, 200))->header('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
        }

if($post->ext == 'rar') {
            return (new Response($file, 200))->header('Content-Type', 'application/x-rar-compressed');
        }
```

Is there a way I can simplify this to reduce the if statements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the only thing that appears to be changing here is the content-type for the output, I'd be inclined to not use code, but a simple and trivially added-to data lookup.

```
<?php
// ....
$extToType = [
    'doc' => 'application/msword',
    'docx' => 'application/msword',
    'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
    // more...  
];

if (isset($extToType[$ext])) {
   return (new Response($file, 200))
       ->header('Content-Type', $extToType[$ext]);
}
```

And now you have a trivial to update data-array, and a couple of lines of code.

Something that actually looked at the contents of the file to return the mime-type would be far preferable however.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a switch()

```
   switch( $post->ext ){

      case 'doc':
      case 'docx':
         return (new Response($file, 200))->header('Content-Type', 'application/msword');
      break;

      case 'xls':
      case 'xlsx':
         return (new Response($file, 200))->header('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint');
      break;

      case 'ppt':
      case 'pptx':
         return (new Response($file, 200))->header('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint');
      break;

      case  'pdf':
        return (new Response($file, 200))->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
      break;

       case  'zip':
        return (new Response($file, 200))->header('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
      break;         
       case  'rar':
        return (new Response($file, 200))->header('Content-Type', 'application/x-rar-compressed');
      break;   

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be manually parsing just create a function to fetch the content type from the extension.

Given that the extension **not** a reliable way of fetching the correct content type I suggest something else such as [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php), but it does require a dependency.

[Switch statements](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

```
 return (new Response($file, 200))->header('Content-Type', this->fetchContentType($file));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all extensions in an array using the content-type as the key.

```
$contentTypes  = ["msword"=>["doc","docx"],"vnd.ms-excel"=>["xls","xlsx"],"vnd.ms-powerpoint"=>["ppt","pptx"],"pdf"=>["pdf"],"zip"=>["zip"],"x-rar-compressed"=>["rar"]];

foreach ($contentTypes as $key=>$type)
{
 if(array_search($post->ext,$type){
   return (new Response($file, 200))->header("Content-Type", "application/{$key}");
  }
}
```